# how to pass a --login into docker build

Tags: bash, docker

I have some script that I need to run inside the container, and somehow it only run if I run it inside a `bash --login`.
I normally run my docker: `docker build -t sometags .` and I noticed it only run `bash` without `--login`.

I know I can just use `bash -l -c "some-command-here"` but I'd say it's my final fallback if nothing can helps.

so, tl;dr: how can I achieve something like this in my Dockerfile

```
#dockerfile
RUN bash --login
RUN some-script
```

and then, I'll just run it with: `docker build -t x/y:z .`

updated: 
the scripts I want to run is things like: gem install bundler, and bundle install.

Comment: Try run them on the same line `RUN bash --login && some-script`

Comment: unfortunately, it raise an error, saying returned a non-zero-code: 2

Comment: I'd figure out why the script needs `--login` personally. Failing that did you try `bash --login some-script`?

Comment: Docker image are expected to be immutable. A login modification would require to build a whole new image. This does not seem a clean nor sustainable way of doing so. IMO, you should find another way to work with it.